# mysql query resulting in blank page with number sign?

Tags: mysql, database, insert

Hoping someone can help me with this: I have a rather long query (about 200 values, shortened here) that I listed below. When I run in mysql I get a weird response: the query does not excecute, but I do not get an error message. When I hit "go" it takes me to a blank page with a # sign in the left hand corner! Anyone have any idea why this is happening? Seems really bizzare.

Here's the query.

```
INSERT INTO staff_access (user_name, user_type) VALUES 
("username1", "reg"), 
...
("username199", "co-op"),
("username200", "co-op");
```

Note - my unique key is an auto-incremented column "user_id", which I did not include in the INSERT INTO query... Not sure if that is relevant.

Thanks for any feedback

-N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this

```
 ORDER BY user_name DESC
```

order is used in `SELECT` statment not `INSERT`

you can get them ordered when you `SELECT` them

Comment: thank you, but is there anyway that I can ensure the usernames are listed in alphabetical order?

Comment: you can get them ordered when you select them

Comment: yeah... okay. I was hoping that I could do it right on insert, but I guess not. Thank you :-)

Comment: nice that it helps you . when u use select get them ordered

Comment: I just tried taking out the ORDER BY part and I get the same thing (number sign in left hand corner)!

Comment: this sign `#` is not from the sql , look something else. this statment now is totally true

Comment: oh! The query did execute, I just didn't get a message telling me so. Thanks again for the quick response!

Comment: if u have other problem u can post other question , now that it solved the query consider to accept the answer as solved

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY` is not valid syntax for `INSERT` statement.

Comment: ok thanks -- know of any way I can order the usernames on insert?

Answer (score 1):

why would you insert with `ORDER BY`?, MySQL it's not last insert last displayed... just do a simple

```
INSERT INTO staff_access (user_name, user_type) VALUES 
("username1", "reg"), 
...
("username199", "co-op"),
("username200", "co-op")
```

and when you make your `select` use the `order by`, if you want to, you could use a index in user_name field and that will 'order by' but it's not 100% sure.

Comment: There is no 'go' in MySQL. You must be using some kind of interface.